# Where does PayPal Access Token go?

Tags: curl, paypal, token

Apparently, according to PayPal, I need an Access Token in my environment, a PayPal Standard, selling one-off items on a single payment.
I've attached what I mean by saying 'an Access Token' - it's a lil box of code that I put my IDs in.
But, where do you paste it, place it?
My PayPal is working OK, but I don't want to leave this code out if the workings need it, it wouldn't be there for s to use otherwise - would it? [picture of access token script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfjb0.png)

Answer (score 0):

An access token is used for server-side REST API calls, such as 'Create Order' and 'Capture Order', [documented here](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/server-side-api-calls/#server-side-api-calls). If you aren't doing server-side REST API calls (or if you are using a Checkout-*-SDK to abstract doing them), you don't need an access token.

(Access tokens expire after ~9 hours, so they can be cached and reused briefly during that time but then a new one needs to be requested for further API calls.)

Comment: That's exactly what's happening, my sales are OK for say, up to around nine hours, then there's nothing. 
But, because I'm using Apache, PayPal says I don't need an API.
I am using my Checkout Live SDK credentials on PayPal Checkout Standard.
Do you think my webserver needs his Apache tweaking, or do I have to renew the Access Token every day? 
Sorry to sound sarcastic, but we never had a performance like this with the html buttons, they were good as gold.

Comment: You need to implement renewing your access token (on a schedule, when it expires, or for every API call) -- or you need to switch to a client-side-only integration that does not use an access token nor API: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client

Comment: Thank you Preston, that's given me something to go on at least.
I'm just searching now to find a way of renewing my access token (on a schedule, when it expires).
The link that you gave is handy, but if I put my ID in the link, it draws a blank, no matter which app that I put in - ah, must be time for another cup of tea! Steve